Scully’s foot fungus cream – A who-has-done-this crossword
This is a cryptic crossword themed on the TV show Brooklyn Nine-Nine. Mild spoilers ahead. No knowledge of the plot or characters is required beyond what’s explained here.

A crime has been committed in the NYPD’s 99th precinct. Someone has stolen Det. Scully’s foot fungus cream. Without it, he may become a living biohazard in a matter of hours. What we have here is a classic who-has-done-this! Let’s meet the victim and suspects.
THE VICTIM
Det. Norm Scully. Overweight, lazy, not very clever. Requires constant medical attention for his numerous physical ailments.
THE SUSPECTS
Det. Charles Boyle. Pleasant, sophisticated, loyal. Possible motive: Favour to a friend. Unlikely to be working alone. Alibi: None.
Det. Rosa Diaz. Tough, smart, scary. Possible motive: None. Would rather die than touch Scully’s gross foot cream. Alibi: None.
Det. Michael Hitchcock. Lazy, careless, makes good coffee. Possible motive: May just have foot fungus. Alibi: None.
Cpt. Raymond Holt. Ambitious, no-nonsense, hates humor. Possible motive: None whatsoever. Alibi: None.
Sgt. Terry Jeffords. Friendly, muscular, hard-working. Possible motive: Proving point about workspace clutter. Alibi: None.
Ms. Gina Linetti. Considers herself a higher class of being. Possible motive: Just sowing chaos. Alibi: None.
Det. Jake Peralta. Extroverted, easily distracted, immature. Possible motive: Prank gone wrong. Alibi: None.
Det. Adrian Pimento. Intense, chaotic, unstable. Possible motive: Impossible to tell. Alibi: None.
Det. Amy Santiago. Uptight, by-the-book, competitive. Possible motive: Obscure protocol. Alibi: None.
THE RULES
A number (between 5 and 10) of “down” answers are too long to fit in the grid and must be shortened by one letter from either the start or the end. Enumerations indicate the length of the space available in the grid, i.e. the length of the answer after shortening. Shortened answers are not necessarily real words. Note the position of the omitted letter in the answer, and highlight one letter of the clue at the same position. For example, if the omitted letter is the fourth letter of the answer, highlight the fourth letter of the clue. These letters, in clue order, spell out the name of the culprit.
In addition, a number (between 5 and 10) of “across” clues have one extra word, which must be removed before solving. The removed words, in clue order, indicate the full truth of what happened to Scully’s stolen foot fungus cream.

Solve on Penpa+ (no answer check)
What’s come across
9. In public, copper shows perhaps excessive manscaping (7)
11. It’s cop has "senile" criminal giving Santiago money? (7,5)
12. Observations about Man and the laws governing him? (12)
13. Property of the Captain has side scratched, with very minor damage (7)
14. A US on RICO bust stealing Peralta’s case? That is just like the Vulture! (9)
15. Scully's been partner to outwit drug smuggler? Right, that got a bit dumb (3,6)
19. Hitchcock's horror: Mamma Maglione's latest gets flipped over in back of cooker (6)
21. War with arrests at focus – Jake, or Amy? (4)
22. Peralta excited about Captain, in the end being on father’s side (8)
25. Peralta exhausted with crooked criminal and taking care of baby? (10)
29. Bumbling his Cap. Stentley misplaces cocaine in portico (10)
31. Bone?? Don't even start, I... (3)
32. Injured Det. Diaz has broken desk arm, which is blown out of proportion (10)
34. Agent close to chief of USPIS eroded station's good 21 across (10)
36. The Ray Holt orderd to guard motorcade, essentially leading to much inappropriate behaviour (8)
38. Appear sulky as vehicle's scraped on the right (4)
40. Lawmen's work over when coming to contact with biting insects (6)
44. Surprising Gina cameo? She really doesn't care for anyone else (9)
47. Stevie Schillins's back, lacking a little insight; hijacks assignment, giving Boyle work (5,4)
50. "Pontiac bandit" ultimately goes missing in whole surprise ordeal (7)
53. Santiago’s heading to take part in probe into a rat – IT: "Getting hacked leads to some very serious issues!" (7,1'4)
54. Place in Regina's governance; amazingly, each time task was close to perfection (12)
55. Continue to openly identify as LBGT? You are no longer welcome! (4,3)
What’s going down
1. Throw off a goon with real slipping foot to reveal space out of limits (2-2,4)
2. City 40 across’s closing in ruined mob plan (8)
3. Legendary criminal in Ianucci’s outfit caught (6)
4. Force to accompany federal agency on tactical initiation, which is a thing that's never happened before (5)
5. The con plays music to dance to (6)
6. Too strict and neat to be participating in bacchanalia? (4)
7. The good guys, in Quebec: "I turned over papers!" (4)
8. Man has endless sexual activity, regularly visiting cute mortician's workplace (6)
10. Pants-wearing woman maybe in grave? Oh yes! (6)
11. "Game of Cheeks" and "Only Slightly Awkward" – assumed headings of Amy's sex tapes? (7)
16. Common slices of lamb are unsanitary; stomach turns (5)
17. Overly hazy memory results from core components of tablet with "cure" (3)
18. Colleague acquiring prepaid phone, to begin with, could be Pimento (5)
20. Have principle to leave patrol officer's usual zone (3)
22. Photos hung up for little dog to get home safe, originally (3-3)
23. Focal bit of Dillman: Intervening in an explosion that's produced a colorful display (5)
24. Preface to song: Singer ingests dash of liquor, getting drunk (6)
26. A doctor begins to intimidate and narcotize Det. Pimento (5)
27. Diabolical environment unending – Madeleine's topping Captain's position, possibly (3)
28. City's defense attorney initially has relaxed mood (6)
30. Player of parts is at it, acting out (3)
33. Giant "Tito" nicked with all network leaders (5)
35. "Hot clue" tracking to government address (3)
37. Escape from jail – a manhunt sequence (3)
39. Private eye working, hauling ass, showing enthusiasm (7)
41. Bystander in bathroom: "Kanalizatsiya!" Explanation repeated, at first continuously (6-2)
42. In plain clothes, disheartened Terry becomes victim (8)
43. PR catastrophe ultimately linked to job change (6)
45. Maybe Swede's endless energy accompanies a victory (6)
46. Black singer with powerful voice described face of attacking hater at sea (6)
48. Cheddar the Corgi gets loose; ends up around area that's more comfortable (6)
49. Terry busts butt supporting squad (5)
51. In interrogation, close to important victory in person? (4)
52. Enjoying Toni broadcast (4)

(Several clues were wholly or partly solved by people other than me -- I posted an incomplete solution when it got to 3am and I needed to go to bed. See below for credits. Oh, and I hadn't even noticed that I failed to actually post a grid image, duh.)
Filled grid:

 

What's come across (with extra words)

 The extra words are: 11:IT'S 15:BEEN 22:IN 29:HIS 32:DESK 36:THE 50:WHOLE 54:TIME.


9. OVERCUT | in OVERT, CU | In public, copper shows perhaps excessive manscaping (7)
11. CHILEAN PESOS | (COP HAS SENILE)* | [It’s] cop has "senile" criminal giving Santiago money? (7,5)
12. COMMANDMENTS | COMMENTS about M AND | Observations about Man and the laws governing him? (12)
13. HOLDING | HOL(-t) + DING | Property of the Captain has side scratched, with very minor damage (7)
14. RAPACIOUS | (A US RICO)* containing P~A | A US on RICO bust stealing Peralta’s case? That is just like the Vulture! (9)
15. FOX MULDER | FOX + MULE R containing D(-umb) | Scully's [been] partner to outwit drug smuggler? Right, that got a bit dumb (3,6)
19. MARNIE | MA ~E contains (IN ~R)< | Hitchcock's horror: Mamma Maglione's latest gets flipped over in back of cooker (6)
21. NAME | NAM + (-arr)E(-sts) | War with arrests at focus – Jake, or Amy? (4)
22. PATERNAL | PERALTA* about ~N | Peralta excited about Captain, [in] the end being on father’s side (8)
25. PARENTHOOD | P(-eralt)A + RENT + HOOD | Peralta exhausted with crooked criminal and taking care of baby? (10)
29. PENTASTYLE | (CAP STENTLEY - C)* | Bumbling [his] Cap. Stentley misplaces cocaine in portico (10)
31. ONE | (-b)ONE | Bone?? Don't even start, I... (3)
32. DRAMATIZED | (DET DIAZ)* containing ARM* | Injured Det. Diaz has broken [desk] arm, which is blown out of proportion (10)
34. REPUTATION | REP + U(-spis) + (-s)TATION | Agent close to chief of USPIS eroded station's good 21 across (10)
36. HARLOTRY | (RAY HOLT)* containing (-moto)R(-cade) | [The] Ray Holt orderd to guard motorcade, essentially leading to much inappropriate behaviour (8)
38. MOPE | MOPE(-d) | Appear sulky as vehicle's scraped on the right (4)
40. POLICE | OP< + LICE | Lawmen's work over when coming to contact with biting insects (6)
44. EGOMANIAC | (GINA CAMEO)* | Surprising Gina cameo? She really doesn't care for anyone else (9)
47. STEVE JOBS | (STEVIE ~S) minus I hijacks JOB | Stevie Schillins's back, lacking a little insight; hijacks assignment, giving Boyle work (5,4)
50. SUNFIRE | STUN FIRE minus (-bandi)T | "Pontiac bandit" ultimately goes missing in [whole] surprise ordeal (7)
52. RAISONS D'ETAT | (S in SONDE) in (A RAT IT)* | Santiago’s heading to take part in probe into a rat – IT: "Getting hacked leads to some very serious issues!" (7,1'4)
54. SASKATCHEWAN | (EACH TASK WAS (-perfectioN)* | Place in Regina's governance; amazingly, each [time] task was close to perfection (12)
55. KEEP OUT | ddef | Continue to openly identify as LBGT? <> You are no longer welcome! (4,3)

What's gone down (with surplus letters)

 The trimmed letters are: 16:N 17:O 23:B 26:O 27:D 30:Y.


1. NO-GO AREA | (A GOON)* + REA(-l) | Throw off a goon with real slipping foot to reveal space out of limits (2-2,4)
2. BELMOPAN | ~E in (MOB PLAN)* | City 40 across’s closing in ruined mob plan (8)
3. ICONIC | CON in I(-anucc)I C | Legendary criminal in Ianucci’s outfit caught (6)
4. FIRST | F + IRS + T(-actical) | Force to accompany federal agency on tactical initiation, which is a thing that's never happened before (5)
5. TECHNO | (THE CON)* | The con plays music to dance to (6)
6. ANAL | substring | Too strict and neat to be participating in bacchanalia? (4)
7. JEDI | JE + ID< | The good guys, in Quebec: "I turned over papers!" (4)
8. MORGUE | M ORG(-y) (-c)U(-t)E | Man has endless sexual activity, regularly visiting cute mortician's workplace (6)
10. TOMBOY | TOMB O Y | Pants-wearing woman maybe in grave? Oh yes! (6)
11. CANASTA | CAN + A(-wkward) containing A~ S~ T~ | "Game of Cheeks" and "Only Slightly Awkward" – assumed headings of Amy's sex tapes? (7)
16. MUTUA[L] | (L~ A~ U~ TUM)< | Common slices of lamb are unsanitary; stomach turns (5)
17. [B]LUR | (-ta)BL(-et) + (-c)UR(-e) | Overly hazy memory results from core components of tablet with "cure" (3)
18. PEPPER | PEER acquiring P~ P~ | Colleague acquiring prepaid phone, to begin with, could be Pimento (5)
20. EAT | B leaves BEAT | Have principle to leave patrol officer's usual zone (3)
22. PIN-UPS | PUP containing IN, plus S(-afe) | Photos hung up for little dog to get home safe, originally (3-3)
23. ABLOO[M] | (-dil)L(-man) in A BOOM | Focal bit of Dillman: Intervening in an explosion that's produced a colorful display (5)
24. SOZZLY | S(-ong) + OZZY ingesting L(-iquor) | Preface to song: Singer ingests dash of liquor, getting drunk (6)
26. ADRIA[N] | A DR I~ A~ N~ | A doctor begins to intimidate and narcotize Det. Pimento (5)
27. [H]ELM | HEL(-l) M(-adeleine) | Diabolical environment unending – Madeleine's topping Captain's position, possibly (3)
28. DODOMA | DA containing MOOD* | City's defense attorney initially has relaxed mood (6)
30. TAT[I] | (AT IT)* | Player of parts is at it, acting out (3)
33. TITAN | TIT(-o) + A~ N~ L~ | Giant "Tito" nicked with all network leaders (5)
35. TIP | (-governmen)T + IP | "Hot clue" tracking to government address (3)
37. LAM | substring | Escape from jail – a manhunt sequence (3)
39. PASSION | PI ON containing ASS | Private eye working, hauling ass, showing enthusiasm (7)
41. LOOKER-ON | LOO + K~ E~ R~ + ON | Bystander in bathroom: "Kanalizatsiya!" Explanation repeated, at first continuously (6-2)
42. CASUALTY | CASUAL + T(-err)Y | In plain clothes, disheartened Terry becomes victim (8)
43. REWORK | ~R ~E + WORK | PR catastrophe ultimately linked to job change (6)
45. GUSTAV | GUST(-o) + A V | Maybe Swede's endless energy accompanies a victory (6)
46. ARETHA | A(-ttacking) + HATER* | Black singer with powerful voice described face of attacking hater at sea (6)
48. EASIER | (~R ~E ~I ~S ~E)< around A | Cheddar the Corgi gets loose; ends up around area that's more comfortable (6)
49. CREWS | (-bust)S under CREW | Terry busts butt supporting squad (5)
51. NIKE | homophone of NIGH KEY | In interrogation, close to important victory in person? (4)
52. INTO | TONI* | Enjoying Toni broadcast (4)

The culprit and explanation, again:

 NOBODY -- IT'S BEEN IN HIS DESK THE WHOLE TIME.

Things I still don't quite understand:

 19a: I haven't watched Marnie but from what I can see it isn't actually a horror movie?
 22a: clue seems better with "in" not removed, but I don't see where else to remove an IN.
 25a: it seems that "crooked" -> RENT, but I don't see how that works.
 20d: Looks like "principle" -> B but I don't see how. (Rosie F and Jeremy Dover suggest that maybe "principal" was intended, in which case it could signify the first letter (of BEAT). Seems possible.)
 35d: Looks like "tracking to" indicates "last letter of" but I don't see how.

Credit where due:

 For 50a I didn't think to check models of Pontiac; Jeremy Dover either did or happened to have them in his head. For 55a I had somehow (... well, it was 3am ...) managed to have STAY OUT at the same time as an incompatible EASIER in 48dn; user39583 pointed out that KEEP OUT is better. I didn't spot "in Quebec, I" in 7d, but user39583 did and so (I think independently) did GentlePurpleRain. I didn't know that CAN (like "cheeks") can mean "buttocks", for 11d; Stiv put me straight. I completely failed to parse 43d, but user39583 didn't. I didn't figure out any of 45d but Jeremy Dover did. I got the answer for 51d but couldn't see the wordplay; Jeremy Dover figured that out.


20d: Perhaps the idea was that rot13(gur svefg yrggre yrnirf "cngeby bssvpre'f hfhny mbar" --- ohg gung ragnvyf zvffcryyvat n pyhr jbeq).

11d Both synonyms for buttocks.

51d - rot13(AVXR = "avtu xrl")

50a - rot13(FHASVER [n Cbagvnp pne zbqry] = F(-g)HA + SVER [beqrny])
45d - rot13(THFGNI = THFG(-b) + N + I [ivpgbel])

Re: 20a - I think "principal" would work here, as indicating the first letter. But that would not fit the surface...

In addition to the ones mentioned by Jeremy, I think rot13(55N vf XRRC + BHG, 7Q vf WR + QV<, 43Q vf _E _R + JBEX).

7D:  rot13(WR + QV<  | Gur tbbq thlf (va Dhrorp, V) + (ghearq bire cncref))
